Is there a way for OpenAPI Generators to generate unit tests, along with the client sdk?
More specifically, given an open api spec, and utilizing the open api generators, I want to generate typescript-axios unit tests, along with the already generating client sdk.

I would to start with something like this https://www.kubb.dev/plugins/swagger-faker/
